# Linq to XML C# Descendants: How to read Attributes with the same name?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I search the Web and found many answers, but they all worked with a specific class or written in another way.

I have this XML-Response:

```
<return xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapResponse_GetItemsBase">
        <ItemsBase xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfPlentysoapobject_itembase">
           <item xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapObject_ItemBase">
              <ItemID xsi:type="xsd:int">2</ItemID>
              <ItemNo xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
               ............. 
              <DeepLink xsi:type="xsd:string">/a-2/</DeepLink>
           </item>
           <item xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapObject_ItemBase">
              <ItemID xsi:type="xsd:int">4</ItemID>
              <ItemNo xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
```

And i read it this way:

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse(readString);
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
            var items = from x in loaded.Descendants("return")
                                select new 
                                {
                                    ItemID = x.Descendants("ItemID").First().Value,
                                    Name = x.Descendants("Name").First().Value,
                                    EKnet = x.Descendants("PurchasePriceNet").First().Value
                                };

                foreach (var x in items)
                {
                    item[i, 0] = x.ItemID.ToString();
                    item[i, 1] = x.Name.ToString();
                    item[i, 2] = x.EKnet.ToString();
                }
            }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong XML Call");
        }
        return item;
      }
```

But I always get the same item Attributes.

Is there an easy way to get the next Item Attributes?
I read an exmaple with "IEnumerable" but this always uses a specific class, wich I dont want to use.

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:GetItemsBaseResponse>  
     <return xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapResponse_GetItemsBase">
        <ItemsBase xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfPlentysoapobject_itembase">
           <item xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapObject_ItemBase">
              <ItemID xsi:type="xsd:int">2</ItemID>
              <ItemNo xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <ExternalItemID xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <EAN1 xsi:type="xsd:string">0023272005641</EAN1>
              <EAN2 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <EAN3 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <EAN4 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <ISBN xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <ASIN xsi:type="xsd:string">B000NTAG66</ASIN>
              <Type xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Type>
              <Model xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <ProducerID xsi:type="xsd:int">0</ProducerID>
              <VATInternalID xsi:type="xsd:int">0</VATInternalID>
              <Marking1ID xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Marking1ID>
              <Marking2ID xsi:type="xsd:int">11</Marking2ID>
              <CustomsTariffNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <FSK xsi:type="xsd:int">0</FSK>
              <Condition xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Condition>
              <Position xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <StorageLocation xsi:type="xsd:int">0</StorageLocation>
              <WebShopSpecial xsi:type="xsd:string">0</WebShopSpecial>
              <Published xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Published>
              <LastUpdate xsi:type="xsd:int">1344392167</LastUpdate>
              <ItemURL xsi:nil="true"/>
              <EbayEPID xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              <ParcelServicePresetIDs xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfPlentysoapobject_integer">
                 <item xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapObject_Integer">
                    <intValue xsi:type="xsd:int">21</intValue>
                 </item>
              </ParcelServicePresetIDs>
              <ProducingCountryID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</ProducingCountryID>
              <FreeTextFields xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapObject_ItemFreeTextFields">
                 <Free1 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                 <Free2 xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[http://games.shop.ebay.de/PC-Videospiele-/1249/i.html?LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=11&Plattform=Xbox%2520360&_trkparms=65%253A12%257C66%253A2%257C39%253A1%257C72%253A4674&rt=nc&_nkw=star+wars+force+unleashed&_catref=1&_dmpt=de_entertainment_games&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14&_sop=15&_sc=1]]></Free2>
                 <Free3 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                 <Free4 xsi:type="xsd:string">1</Free4>
                 <Free5 xsi:type="xsd:string">UK-Import: Spiel in Deutsch, Anleitung in Englisch</Free5>
                 <Free6 xsi:type="xsd:string">Actionspiele</Free6>
                 <Free7 xsi:type="xsd:string">XBOX 360</Free7>
                 <Free8 xsi:type="xsd:string">ages_12_and_over</Free8>
                 <Free9 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                 <Free10 xsi:type="xsd:string">1</Free10>
                 <Free11 xsi:type="xsd:string">0</Free11>
                 <Free12 xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <Free13 xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <Free14 xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <Free15 xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <Free16 xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <Free17 xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <Free18 xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <Free19 xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <Free20 xsi:nil="true"/>
              </FreeTextFields>
              <Texts xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapObject_ItemTexts">
                 <Lang xsi:type="xsd:string">de</Lang>
                 <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Star Wars: The Force Unleashed 1 - Xbox 360</Name>
                 <Name2 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                 <Name3 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                 <ShortDescription xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <LongDescription xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <TechnicalData xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <MetaDescription xsi:nil="true"/>
                 <Keywords xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
              </Texts>
              <PriceSet xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapObject_ItemPriceSet">
                 <PriceID xsi:type="xsd:int">2</PriceID>
                 <Lot xsi:type="xsd:float">0</Lot>
                 <Unit xsi:type="xsd:string">C62</Unit>
                 <Unit1 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                 <Unit2 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                 <PackagingUnit xsi:type="xsd:string">1</PackagingUnit>
                 <Price xsi:type="xsd:float">20.99</Price>
                 <Price1 xsi:type="xsd:float">18.65</Price1>
                 <Price2 xsi:type="xsd:float">23.99</Price2>
                 <Price3 xsi:type="xsd:float">999</Price3>
                 <Price4 xsi:type="xsd:float">999</Price4>
                 <Price5 xsi:type="xsd:float">0</Price5>
                 <Price6 xsi:type="xsd:float">0</Price6>
                 <Price7 xsi:type="xsd:float">0</Price7>
                 <Price8 xsi:type="xsd:float">0</Price8>
                 <Price9 xsi:type="xsd:float">0</Price9>
                 <Price10 xsi:type="xsd:float">0</Price10>
                 <Price11 xsi:type="xsd:float">23.7</Price11>
                 <Price12 xsi:type="xsd:float">33.7</Price12>
                 <RRP xsi:type="xsd:float">0</RRP>
                 <VAT xsi:type="xsd:float">19</VAT>
                 <WeightInGramm xsi:type="xsd:int">0</WeightInGramm>
                 <WidthInMM xsi:type="xsd:int">0</WidthInMM>
                 <LengthInMM xsi:type="xsd:int">0</LengthInMM>
                 <HeightInMM xsi:type="xsd:int">0</HeightInMM>
                 <Position xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Position>
                 <ShowOnly xsi:type="xsd:int">0</ShowOnly>
                 <RebateLevelPrice6 xsi:type="xsd:int">0</RebateLevelPrice6>
                 <RebateLevelPrice7 xsi:type="xsd:int">0</RebateLevelPrice7>
                 <RebateLevelPrice8 xsi:type="xsd:int">0</RebateLevelPrice8>
                 <PurchasePriceNet xsi:type="xsd:float">14.38</PurchasePriceNet>
                 <Package xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Package>
                 <TypeOfPackage xsi:type="xsd:int">0</TypeOfPackage>
                 <UnitLoadDevice xsi:type="xsd:int">0</UnitLoadDevice>
              </PriceSet>
              <Stock xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapObject_ItemStock">
                 <Limitation xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Limitation>
                 <MainWarehouseID xsi:type="xsd:int">2</MainWarehouseID>
                 <WebshopVisiblePositiveStock xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</WebshopVisiblePositiveStock>
                 <WebshopInvisibleNoStock xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</WebshopInvisibleNoStock>
                 <ChangeAvailablePositiveStock xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</ChangeAvailablePositiveStock>
                 <ChangeNotAvailableNoStock xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</ChangeNotAvailableNoStock>
                 <ChangeAvailablePositiveStockVariant xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</ChangeAvailablePositiveStockVariant>
                 <ChangeNotAvailableNoStockVariant xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</ChangeNotAvailableNoStockVariant>
                 <StorageLocation xsi:nil="true"/>
              </Stock>
              <Availability xsi:type="ns1:PlentySoapObject_ItemAvailability">
                 <AvailabilityID xsi:type="xsd:int">5</AvailabilityID>
                 <Webshop xsi:type="xsd:int">1</Webshop>
                 <WebAPI xsi:type="xsd:int">1</WebAPI>
                 <Inactive xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Inactive>
                 <AmazonFBA xsi:type="xsd:int">1</AmazonFBA>
                 <AmazonFEDAS xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                 <AmazonProduct xsi:type="xsd:int">31</AmazonProduct>
                 <Gimahhot xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Gimahhot>
                 <GoogleBase xsi:type="xsd:int">0</GoogleBase>
                 <Hitmeister xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Hitmeister>
                 <MeinPaket xsi:type="xsd:int">0</MeinPaket>
                 <Mercateo xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Mercateo>
                 <Quelle xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Quelle>
                 <Moebelprofi xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Moebelprofi>
                 <Zalando xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Zalando>
                 <Restposten xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Restposten>
                 <Shopgate xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Shopgate>
                 <Shopperella xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Shopperella>
                 <ShopShare xsi:type="xsd:int">0</ShopShare>
                 <Tradoria xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Tradoria>
                 <TradoriaCategory xsi:type="xsd:int">0</TradoriaCategory>
                 <Yatego xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Yatego>
                 <AvailableUntil xsi:type="xsd:int">0</AvailableUntil>
                 <MaximumSalesOrderQuantity xsi:type="xsd:int">0</MaximumSalesOrderQuantity>
                 <Neckermann xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Neckermann>
              </Availability>
              <Others xsi:nil="true"/>
              <Categories xsi:nil="true"/>
              <AttributeValueSets xsi:nil="true"/>
              <ItemSuppliers xsi:nil="true"/>
              <ItemProperties xsi:nil="true"/>
              <ItemAttributeMarkup xsi:nil="true"/>
              <BundleType xsi:nil="true"/>
              <DeepLink xsi:type="xsd:string">/a-2/</DeepLink>
           </item>
```

Comment: What is the content of `readString` variable?

Comment: string readString = send_recv(document);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse(readString);
        var items = loaded
                    .Descendants("return")
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .Element("ItemsBase")
                    .Elements("item");
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var _item in items)
        {
            item[i, 0] = _item.Element("ItemID").Value;
            item[i, 1] = _item.Element("Texts").Element("Name").Value;
            item[i, 2] = _item.Element("PriceSet").Element("PurchasePriceNet").Value;
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: With that Code i get an error :
_System.nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object_
In the line `item[i, 1] = _item.Element("Name").Value;`

Comment: Name is probably not (always) in your return xml? In your question you do use Name, where is that one comming from?

Comment: Yeah, "Name" is part of <`Texts`>

Comment: It possibly means that the element with name `Name` was not found. Is it possible that element named `item` doesn't always have a child element named `ItemID`,`Name`,`PurchasePriceNet`? Is `item` a multidimensional array, like `object[,] item`? If there isn't an element named `Name`, should it's place in array remain empty?

Comment: `Name` is always a child element of `Texts`. and `Texts` a child of `item`.

item is a multidimensional array.
The `Name` Element is always filled.

I think there is only problem that `Name` is a child to `Texts`

Comment: Thanks, but same issue as before, but now with `ItemID`
in the line:`item[i, 0] = _item.Element("ItemID").Value;`

Comment: Is it possible that `ItemID` is missing for some of the `item` elements?

Comment: No the xml response only calls Articles with an ItemID

Comment: Can you post the entire return value of `send_recv(document);`, i.e. content of `readString` after the call to `send_recv`?

Comment: there you go. This is the first out of 50 Articles the xml response gives.

Comment: Same error code but now at the top of the function.
So it doesnt work , too

Comment: OK, I made some more adjustments and it seems to be working for the XML segment that you posted, you can try it...

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var items = from ret in xdoc.Descendants("return")
                    from itb in ret.Descendants("ItemsBase")
                    from item in itb.Descendants("item")
                    select new {item};

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            // do what you want with item,
        }
```

Comment: '\ItemsBase\Item' Doesn't work.
And I try to get all 50 other Items, aswell

Comment: `loaded.XPathSelectElements` doesnt excised in my XDocument "loaded"

Comment: I tryed our code, but 
`select new { ItemID = itm.Descendants("ItemID").First().Value };`
and  `foreach....{item[i, 0] = itm.ItemID.ToString();}`

Calls an error that _The Sequence has no Elements_